# Ext.Net delete from database(Just Client deleting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ext.net

i'm trying to use ext.net gridpanel in my projet.The point is i cannot delete store datas from database.i added row command and button for try to deletion with direct method.But not fired.I'm using entity framework at the code behind and storing gridpanel with it.How can i delete or edit stores from database when i click to row command deletion or editing.Am i missin proxy or another method?I m new at ext.net.

**

```
<ext:GridPanel
        ID="GridPanel1"
        runat="server" 
        Title="Control Test" 
        Width="700">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server" OnReadData="Store1_ReadData" AutoSync="true" PageSize="10">
                <Model>
                    <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:ModelField Name="ID" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Controllor"  />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Process" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="Control"  />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="ControlType" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="ControlPlace" />
                            <ext:ModelField Name="AuditeeUnit" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:Model>
                </Model>  


            </ext:Store>

        </Store>

        <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:RowNumbererColumn ID="RowNumbererColumn1" runat="server" Width="35" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" Text="Controllor" DataIndex="Controllor" Flex="1" />
                <ext:Column ID="Column2" runat="server" Text="Process" Width="75" DataIndex="Process">

                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column ID="Column3" runat="server" Text="Control" Width="75" DataIndex="Control">

                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column ID="Column4" runat="server" Text="Control Type" Width="75" DataIndex="ControlType">

                </ext:Column>
                  <ext:Column ID="Column5" runat="server" Text="Control Area" Width="75" DataIndex="ControlPlace">

                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="Unit" Width="75" DataIndex="AuditeeUnit">

                </ext:Column>
               <ext:CommandColumn ID="CommandColumn1" runat="server" Width="60">
                    <Commands>
                        <ext:GridCommand Icon="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnDataBinding="Unnamed_DataBinding" AutoDataBind="True">                              
                            <ToolTip Text="Delete" />

                        </ext:GridCommand>
                        <ext:CommandSeparator />
                        <ext:GridCommand Icon="NoteEdit" CommandName="Edit">
                            <ToolTip Text="Edit" />
                        </ext:GridCommand>
                    </Commands>
                    <Listeners>                           
                        <Command Handler="if (command == 'Delete') {App.direct.testmethod();}"/>
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:CommandColumn>

            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <TopBar>

               <ext:Toolbar ID="UsersGridPanelPowerUserToolbar" runat="server">
                  <Items>                         
                     <ext:Button ID="UserRemoveButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" Icon="Delete" Disabled="false" StandOut="true">

                          <Listeners>

                           <Click Handler="App.direct.testmethod();" /> 
                        </Listeners>
                          <DirectEvents>
                           <Click  OnEvent="Unnamed_Event"></Click>

                           </DirectEvents>

                     </ext:Button>
                     <ext:ToolbarSeparator></ext:ToolbarSeparator>

                  </Items>
               </ext:Toolbar>
            </TopBar>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel ID="CheckboxSelectionModel1" runat="server" Mode="Multi" />
        </SelectionModel>
        <View>
            <ext:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" StripeRows="true" />                   
        </View>            
        <BottomBar>
             <ext:PagingToolbar ID="PagingToolbar1" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Page size:" />
                    <ext:ToolbarSpacer ID="ToolbarSpacer1" runat="server" Width="10" />
                    <ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" Width="80">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:ListItem Text="1" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="2" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="10" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="20" />
                        </Items>
                        <SelectedItems>
                            <ext:ListItem Value="10" />
                        </SelectedItems>
                        <Listeners>
                            <Select Handler="#{GridPanel1}.store.pageSize = parseInt(this.getValue(), 10); #{GridPanel1}.store.reload();" />
                        </Listeners>
                    </ext:ComboBox>
                </Items>
                <Plugins>                      
                    <ext:ProgressBarPager ID="ProgressBarPager1" runat="server" />
                </Plugins>
            </ext:PagingToolbar>
        </BottomBar>
    </ext:GridPanel>
```

**

```
 [DirectMethod]
    public void testmethod()
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("DirectMethod", "hello").Show();

        ModelProxy prox = new ModelProxy(Store1);
        //AbstractProxy absprox = JsonPProxy
        prox.Store.DataBind();
        //prox.Destroy();
        //prox.Store.ServerProxy.RemoveAt();
        prox.Store.Destroy();//tested for data deletion

        Store1.CommitChanges();//it has sent communicate for changed data at server data

    }
```

Comment: Please demonstrate the definition of the "testmethod" DirectMethod.

Comment: Just i tested deletion but not changed at server side.I used simple delete function at aspx in ext.net examples but just client deleted.

Comment: Please clarify is the "testmethod" executed or not?

Comment: Today it fired.Maybe it can be a bug about vs2012.But still not founded deletion from sql

Comment: "not founded deletion from SQL" - do you mean that you don't know how to delete records from a SQL database?

Comment: Yes i couldn't send commit or delete command from client to sql.I m missing something.

Comment: At the moment I am not very fluent in SQL. I would create a stored procedure on the database level and call it in code behind.

Comment: Just i need a call statement for database.Ext.ne has commit and many functions.But i couldn't see any examples about this.Just has simple record on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228366%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

just change the connectionstring to your own and the `SELECT` statement with something like

```
"DELETE FROM <Table> WHERE ID= "+selectedRowID
```

be sure to provide the *serverside method* the `ID` of the selected Row:

```
App.direct.testmethod(record.data.ID);
```

Comment: Your right but i m using entityframework and linq so i have a model.In this point when i add to store some data,the ext.net grid is giving different id for rows so i cannot checking my gird id to database id.Those are showing different.

Comment: You have the ModelField 'ID', don't you fill that with your records ID from your DB?

Comment: Yes i filled but its a guid and i hidden it from grid for design.When i tried to call ids,its calling first column as a id so i cannot merging them with database.

Comment: record.data.ID as parameter should give you the right ID if you loaded the right ID from DB into that field...

Comment: Thank you very much MMMagic i solved the problem with this.You saved my day.thx